# Non numeric argument to binary argument error when estimating a panel VAR

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a Panel VAR in R using the `panelvar` package. I have tried running the following chunk of code and it gives me an error

```
library(panelvar)

finaldata <- read.csv(file = "panelset.csv", sep = ";", 
                      header = TRUE)

colnames(finaldata) <- c("Country","Period","Debt","Equity","Fed","US GDP")


panel_regression <-
  pvarfeols(dependent_vars = "Debt",
            lags = 1,
            exog_vars = c("Fed","US GDP"),
            data = finaldata,
            panel_identifier= c("Country", "Period"))

summary(panel_regression)
```

the error which I get is

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “texreg” object: invalid object for slot "model.name" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "character"

Error in x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong here?

I've reproduced my dataset below (apologies it is quite long)

```
structure(list(Country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil"), 
    Period = c("1991-01-01", "1991-04-01", "1991-07-01", "1991-10-01", 
    "1992-01-01", "1992-04-01", "1992-07-01", "1992-10-01", "1993-01-01", 
    "1993-04-01", "1993-07-01", "1993-10-01", "1994-01-01", "1994-04-01", 
    "1994-07-01", "1994-10-01", "1995-01-01", "1995-04-01", "1995-07-01", 
    "1995-10-01", "1996-01-01", "1996-04-01", "1996-07-01", "1996-10-01", 
    "1997-01-01", "1997-04-01", "1997-07-01", "1997-10-01", "1998-01-01", 
    "1998-04-01", "1998-07-01", "1998-10-01", "1999-01-01", "1999-04-01", 
    "1999-07-01", "1999-10-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-04-01", "2000-07-01", 
    "2000-10-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-04-01", "2001-07-01", "2001-10-01", 
    "2002-01-01", "2002-04-01", "2002-07-01", "2002-10-01", "2003-01-01", 
    "2003-04-01", "2003-07-01", "2003-10-01", "2004-01-01", "2004-04-01", 
    "2004-07-01", "2004-10-01", "2005-01-01", "2005-04-01", "2005-07-01", 
    "2005-10-01", "2006-01-01", "2006-04-01", "2006-07-01", "2006-10-01", 
    "2007-01-01", "2007-04-01", "2007-07-01", "2007-10-01", "2008-01-01", 
    "2008-04-01", "2008-07-01", "2008-10-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-04-01", 
    "2009-07-01", "2009-10-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-07-01", 
    "2010-10-01", "2011-01-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", 
    "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-10-01", "2013-01-01", 
    "2013-04-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-10-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-04-01", 
    "2014-07-01", "2014-10-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-07-01", 
    "2015-10-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-10-01", 
    "2017-01-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-07-01", "2017-10-01", "2018-01-01", 
    "2018-04-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-10-01", "1991-01-01", "1991-04-01", 
    "1991-07-01", "1991-10-01", "1992-01-01", "1992-04-01", "1992-07-01", 
    "1992-10-01", "1993-01-01", "1993-04-01", "1993-07-01", "1993-10-01", 
    "1994-01-01", "1994-04-01", "1994-07-01", "1994-10-01", "1995-01-01", 
    "1995-04-01", "1995-07-01", "1995-10-01", "1996-01-01", "1996-04-01", 
    "1996-07-01", "1996-10-01", "1997-01-01", "1997-04-01", "1997-07-01", 
    "1997-10-01", "1998-01-01", "1998-04-01", "1998-07-01", "1998-10-01", 
    "1999-01-01", "1999-04-01", "1999-07-01", "1999-10-01", "2000-01-01", 
    "2000-04-01", "2000-07-01", "2000-10-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-04-01", 
    "2001-07-01", "2001-10-01", "2002-01-01", "2002-04-01", "2002-07-01", 
    "2002-10-01", "2003-01-01", "2003-04-01", "2003-07-01", "2003-10-01", 
    "2004-01-01", "2004-04-01", "2004-07-01", "2004-10-01", "2005-01-01", 
    "2005-04-01", "2005-07-01", "2005-10-01", "2006-01-01", "2006-04-01", 
    "2006-07-01", "2006-10-01", "2007-01-01", "2007-04-01", "2007-07-01", 
    "2007-10-01", "2008-01-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-07-01", "2008-10-01", 
    "2009-01-01", "2009-04-01", "2009-07-01", "2009-10-01", "2010-01-01", 
    "2010-04-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-10-01", "2011-01-01", "2011-04-01", 
    "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", 
    "2012-10-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-04-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-10-01", 
    "2014-01-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-10-01", "2015-01-01", 
    "2015-04-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-10-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-04-01", 
    "2016-07-01", "2016-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-07-01", 
    "2017-10-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-10-01"
    ), Debt = c(0.399188457454692, 0.022672297678146, 0.0116136537493237, 
    7.92454610383002, 0.945931372962904, 0.524297636454574, 0.468153696381207, 
    0.154516550710679, 0.757055779332188, 22.1975840458252, 0.902900351272925, 
    3.71828939409316, 1.46737458508695, 0.125546208703621, 1.68072199307099, 
    1.95776335373338, -0.970156572166896, 0.995295199649776, 
    1.13274921779538, 1.87192742714579, 2.82885492851474, 1.74627220364152, 
    2.24304913308424, 2.21864154888705, 3.44477381023249, 1.29258037701881, 
    2.03933972922678, 1.09096730841007, 2.67277749906074, 3.14794334492405, 
    2.04809125207211, 0.114476927983192, 0.624027318412421, 2.18877850647622, 
    0.0654976908247524, 1.72135205824217, 1.98766307724775, 1.03180516387514, 
    -0.193944962853301, -1.27476779414629, -2.24680266145076, 
    -1.21934710551748, -2.37071736665319, -2.21068117757116, 
    -2.09559026697161, -0.791630759675286, 0.0939386661551566, 
    -1.07606630432647, -1.3683822728305, -1.17638994043959, -0.289398518904522, 
    -1.68500622147193, -1.88025000334968, -0.488635248102927, 
    -0.996143590796292, -0.940827238906696, -1.33546527911977, 
    -0.264639521122357, 0.369377679177478, 0.407831286787086, 
    0.940854951371161, 0.577138587792623, 0.257191375916894, 
    0.656536970193242, 0.574258570348317, 1.28243057447825, -0.361485630591475, 
    0.235029475677136, -0.0482548183823018, -0.227042651665518, 
    -0.404501252901892, -0.288958774661623, 0.0190098577943049, 
    -0.0520776519630017, -0.108694434808055, -0.075767097824521, 
    0.0628142752097266, 0.0188652295168775, 0.0433128292456203, 
    0.223580835144585, 0.0927890278385013, 0.0281848266804217, 
    -0.0230915265530824, -0.0834253617055194, 0.145621177917445, 
    0.0022400413466608, -0.118256436774812, 0.00958639661323493, 
    0.0128251314942033, -0.0368849916552845, -0.0162227057609669, 
    0.0741352632315612, 0.0652508490970146, -0.203389396134579, 
    0.0253855602636785, 0.00278144447135972, 0.049958774279819, 
    0.0512451654440406, 0.0223614649637565, -0.0961718772887949, 
    0.150767272514635, 0.335698329491662, 0.183436421451835, 
    0.271410205989672, 0.381682681582479, 0.0932622958503815, 
    0.122772645990229, 0.231273984544996, 0.292407184603114, 
    -0.0195239111310146, -0.0157513276278353, -0.00947249024963098, 
    8675.33960685515, 6768.49347907192, 8642.32842113652, 6778.29680089139, 
    4408.40805853892, 3895.82777919365, 574.508463179, 350.221423532295, 
    102.632073797281, 218.57734281563, 52.7550010828693, 36.3087661140996, 
    10.3933818990146, 77.1007386023752, 0.728312592509668, 1.49123521955624, 
    -1.41889856944463, 2.00361935198012, 3.04584017874769, 1.80541578084482, 
    1.49761321234702, 2.84258838937904, 1.51407226558065, 3.84975451276157, 
    0.926983209580913, 1.29901800202752, 2.37950729064367, -1.40774364951685, 
    4.50116050799728, 3.3278240935673, 1.36904358609848, 2.44914709265132, 
    -4.02166298149232, 1.88279127233971, 0.07283219201171, 2.09614224934677, 
    1.55374478096676, -0.0397551704508088, 1.01723984267357, 
    0.125072377416065, 0.883933692566263, -0.769589567934816, 
    0.667825646236349, -1.36074643013475, 0.572569989230368, 
    -0.822373227817192, -1.07886661801643, -1.06153022608166, 
    0.328067155736612, 0.799718640056857, -0.356860759660434, 
    -0.0208990517809473, 0.508150591204836, -1.6119559653249, 
    -0.103127087879746, -0.455901345923868, 0.911917235929434, 
    -0.0653560177657754, -0.476028608366156, -0.221855292115599, 
    0.905680315230707, -2.26671649683073, 0.637174497272548, 
    0.928616026071915, 1.42071541759014, 2.09324089680791, 0.918979279547152, 
    0.134720953403986, 1.60891903858651, 0.0345376414099952, 
    1.25310348581207, -1.53001136372104, -0.641401845987443, 
    0.471069636604668, 1.00696350840985, 0.551429348652744, 0.838460817647529, 
    1.39941272511458, 1.71549383195025, 0.8836818195945, 1.02749789738806, 
    0.502240545360886, 0.514556786854289, 0.193509661158828, 
    0.598664230154735, 0.328424051447386, 0.817383230248266, 
    0.2936214536215, 0.474639783240399, 1.06329136238065, 1.83236330018908, 
    -0.211237832907205, 1.45416659952361, 1.08663342848816, 0.97310506863358, 
    -0.294092343295468, 1.28034099491235, 0.321000004827693, 
    -0.856493640790065, -0.275345657700502, -0.906791658206871, 
    -0.552780238399426, -0.777353026272904, -0.578455641947713, 
    -0.375786917591634, -0.0123005576691823, -0.119711524198227, 
    -0.421053691574254, 0.346540002816572, 0.0305069960047579, 
    -0.107619362609426, -0.505660656454291), Equity = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.352359875423383, -0.0264636766842375, 0.568285327016238, 
    0.334852707002202, 0.26231179217413, 0.371440902669924, 3.14780400895305, 
    1.34878677517818, 0.889494470250186, -0.185533394765037, 
    1.77691651540281, 0.809572541637369, 0.559607007311109, 0.348867524469454, 
    0.0490477281742154, 0.370052722281471, 0.538083761987755, 
    0.372121189338971, -0.423217564624216, 0.238734625090676, 
    0.37850738550575, 0.0667923340845627, 1.38124603283145, -0.0815232752749664, 
    0.437201461771531, -0.352168993293173, -0.0473105328019396, 
    -0.153520025233019, -0.0776883617514691, -8.02987530373638, 
    -0.239018215519733, 0.135783176299915, 0.229022592428566, 
    -0.0708755344297144, -2.6442853419507, 0.0321871379778304, 
    0.0250431578784324, -0.0265294704559886, -0.0559913853586795, 
    0.0915890531828827, 0.00359952287675745, 0.0117807216223086, 
    -0.00790119852710366, -0.0813886517186671, 0.0329314639963431, 
    0.0109982637584835, -0.0394346001990275, 0.0353232419955134, 
    -0.0304096380549101, 0.0140628744418867, -0.00533522930908469, 
    -0.020165421394489, -0.00143828082710788, -0.0125648862419161, 
    -0.0252516571856573, 0.0203250722166047, 0.0844282096537696, 
    0.0334489655166707, 0.0398498095283641, 0.0624836844392056, 
    0.156169507368477, 0.14467590109694, 0.054967201670676, 0.0909725682499244, 
    -0.0197923369134106, -0.0367547363467296, -0.0108093443737543, 
    -0.0332443116263239, -0.0144530937223576, 0.00182833147091003, 
    -0.00940258487990617, -0.0153717985570273, -0.0333931868985005, 
    -0.0107623019793156, 0.0123224487134972, 0.0157462673396441, 
    -0.00594006176008805, 0.00843850695235495, 0.0123735631007477, 
    -0.0347449495443311, -0.00273925186114371, -0.000922594947191017, 
    -0.00943006645793724, 0.00165206961662809, 0.00606358780505324, 
    0.0017727342564021, -0.00027066834114367, 0.0142919457910773, 
    0.000824463764159478, 0.0108156903234997, 0.00311164941146048, 
    -0.00414148324529025, 0.00183666378585208, 0.000855937859844001, 
    -0.00161514084021847, 0.00745365459516936, 0.000942065109155325, 
    0.00102913902624391, 0.0111329840327704, 0.0124742985213583, 
    0.0012277177174528, 0.0181740724741895, 0.0317088354696782, 
    0.00967584767120874, 0.00182486058379987, -0.004515744306543, 
    -0.00192397304315985, -0.00243044899419261, 1624.15033735644, 
    1550.32532202206, 1820.89700423946, 903.772906785519, 2139.12483456702, 
    935.486216826319, 125.101010706107, 75.0474478997775, 129.070762179136, 
    74.6269264032566, 55.7074164601138, 61.5548340488237, 20.7500380669373, 
    5.98731316058274, 0.3646957870641, 1.27717741674906, -1.81735638689141, 
    0.975018979630523, 2.51281814746685, 0.255311322543712, 1.2434949802275, 
    0.662705946320072, 0.7661118036671, 1.09206730723184, 1.83055455653077, 
    1.88899363906202, 1.04867279885882, -1.54480480391123, 2.81763706655867, 
    1.90688117813969, -4.6401335987231, -0.749220780217773, 0.138277505896449, 
    0.913790995701184, 0.0440027826737415, 0.218662320975023, 
    0.123536054595975, 0.632736255925971, 0.651889786264367, 
    0.0175727927856908, 0.394637475773554, 0.429573632035573, 
    0.232036962156958, 0.012902486761253, 0.505000983299055, 
    0.28489287431765, -0.280412133458802, 0.259441873324194, 
    0.0488855737879238, 0.164951278829269, 0.247932771142615, 
    0.46430526919631, 0.256832925251124, -0.00276214550927664, 
    -0.0361825576143476, 0.368672038317538, 0.711139840669095, 
    -0.0136368515792298, 0.550899850901043, 0.415164995179914, 
    0.661197061463859, 0.35674139024198, 0.135936590065625, 0.628192287997731, 
    0.573202531491154, 1.02813326454511, 1.43160077943277, 2.19326092079145, 
    -0.402446855038294, 1.24227676677669, -0.624522794817686, 
    -1.48454573814886, -0.00608845819027901, 0.528552583138629, 
    2.31448621781984, 2.98296280598812, 0.824393093516982, 0.655427862092698, 
    1.30584343705957, 2.43084687393693, 0.102047199316653, 0.397666178469535, 
    0.260555590211225, 0.145535544136514, 0.637496399699944, 
    -0.268927009421089, 0.000168590201350587, 0.294562050349593, 
    0.792183225605227, -0.0855284582028586, 0.345907968261936, 
    0.144175132596329, 0.0319541440311953, 0.85000557915344, 
    0.214747724250854, 0.017387031791737, 0.397492774876008, 
    0.619157599280696, -0.0575863603066823, -0.0333293719167664, 
    0.268277762092734, 0.27684834070109, 0.171209533349781, 0.261533557108659, 
    -0.0575244424367011, -0.0531255278387395, 0.367310741515481, 
    0.212382962510098, 0.00621698189822234, -0.327423361676478, 
    0.109115915365989, -0.239232364356364), Fed = c(23.498, 23.261, 
    23.174, 25.403, 22.646, 21.208, 23.634, 23.645, 26.965, 26.524, 
    28.277, 27.791, 29.602, 25.995, 24.738, 22.266, 24.193, 20.815, 
    20.039, 17.776, 19.236, 15.411, 12.811, 11.679, 12.247, 9.876, 
    9.995, 9.748, 11.166, 9.648, 9.031, 9.647, 9.199, 7.585, 
    6.774, 5.165, 7.102, 6.801, 6.729, 6.925, 6.84, 7.686, 12.074, 
    9.991, 9.712, 8.036, 8.778, 10.073, 10.595, 12.177, 11.598, 
    11.579, 14.091, 13.315, 11.924, 14.073, 12.906, 11.503, 10.252, 
    10.272, 10.304, 9.688, 8.225, 8.75, 8.509, 8.296, 8.275, 
    8.665, 9.751, 10.51, 278.018, 820.669, 844.528, 758.906, 
    1017.767, 1070.701, 1076.456, 1046.938, 998.508, 1066.213, 
    1484.147, 1652.208, 1592.447, 1568.915, 1537.808, 1535.052, 
    1476.73, 1582.524, 1832.952, 2094.225, 2374.958, 2498.153, 
    2660.368, 2704.004, 2705.668, 2683.709, 2698.96, 2590.841, 
    2668.193, 2376.108, 2427.737, 2309.659, 2095.127, 2092.776, 
    2281.42, 2233.323, 2245.701, 2214.601, 2086.192, 1949.82, 
    1830.017, 1639.03, 23.498, 23.261, 23.174, 25.403, 22.646, 
    21.208, 23.634, 23.645, 26.965, 26.524, 28.277, 27.791, 29.602, 
    25.995, 24.738, 22.266, 24.193, 20.815, 20.039, 17.776, 19.236, 
    15.411, 12.811, 11.679, 12.247, 9.876, 9.995, 9.748, 11.166, 
    9.648, 9.031, 9.647, 9.199, 7.585, 6.774, 5.165, 7.102, 6.801, 
    6.729, 6.925, 6.84, 7.686, 12.074, 9.991, 9.712, 8.036, 8.778, 
    10.073, 10.595, 12.177, 11.598, 11.579, 14.091, 13.315, 11.924, 
    14.073, 12.906, 11.503, 10.252, 10.272, 10.304, 9.688, 8.225, 
    8.75, 8.509, 8.296, 8.275, 8.665, 9.751, 10.51, 278.018, 
    820.669, 844.528, 758.906, 1017.767, 1070.701, 1076.456, 
    1046.938, 998.508, 1066.213, 1484.147, 1652.208, 1592.447, 
    1568.915, 1537.808, 1535.052, 1476.73, 1582.524, 1832.952, 
    2094.225, 2374.958, 2498.153, 2660.368, 2704.004, 2705.668, 
    2683.709, 2698.96, 2590.841, 2668.193, 2376.108, 2427.737, 
    2309.659, 2095.127, 2092.776, 2281.42, 2233.323, 2245.701, 
    2214.601, 2086.192, 1949.82, 1830.017, 1639.03), `US GDP` = c(23828960375.2496, 
    24570173835.2461, 24618482576.232, 25322940253.7602, 24336863756.7546, 
    25189608620.1855, 25320123456.7901, 26204913699.8426, 24875012907.1837, 
    25699143936.2022, 25918981345.8125, 26828862297.4798, 25723264850.2275, 
    26661451012.6325, 26817952935.6474, 27730546144.1877, 26430891276.2001, 
    27130746121.828, 27368358875.1632, 28188874478.1227, 26963733022.6122, 
    27902101794.5407, 28122691451.4785, 28976253131.2815, 27850026848.0889, 
    28969221937.7692, 29306253136.5783, 30253487806.1969, 29048298910.932, 
    30098753739.0504, 30408387402.9014, 31540170612.6837, 30305991372.9305, 
    31338089796.3896, 31478882110.9967, 32715418840.0953, 31194414618.8931, 
    32499342291.6582, 32363862784.4326, 33280770262.2431, 31711315251.1413, 
    32541277413.1269, 32424964717.3351, 33463380983.8784, 32092466233.7266, 
    33020136505.9471, 33171345823.9365, 34079628256.821, 32485169975.5783, 
    33622439895.2574, 33993253465.9877, 35429094721.0003, 34001121694.55, 
    34866580379.3729, 35240004638.9912, 36545672465.4354, 35073369491.6478, 
    36224490596.7095, 36259363054.5303, 37567995497.0677, 36386704937.3554, 
    37205987767.8273, 37218518705.595, 38417875805.5523, 36948176889.2117, 
    37791365777.0801, 37971495597.3698, 38731965495.01, 37206028775.465, 
    36917087783.2509, 36706267890.3179, 38191521030.4293, 35992161815.5556, 
    36328927601.6361, 36519919105.9246, 37637437647.6766, 35992567528.9789, 
    37456234337.25, 37719401572.6337, 38572862611.8239, 36575417855.0902, 
    37493078351.3241, 37614093088.966, 38643839335.8385, 37524964614.649, 
    38352377413.9263, 38363154075.9308, 39337840045.2824, 37935426334.949, 
    38883827474.8867, 39433742625.5233, 40579643699.2402, 38698152610.1453, 
    39847178231.6809, 40765220450.217, 42052245216.3496, 40460169979.1012, 
    41696304154.5481, 42291908179.2464, 43011309107.3024, 41103224973.4678, 
    42325826513.2009, 42762218814.183, 43473515269.0922, 41587129237.9987, 
    43295806067.6844, 43650735173.9407, 44802283124.4096, 42964921202.462, 
    44493262917.9686, 45003489732.068, 46099768086.1553, 23828960375.2496, 
    24570173835.2461, 24618482576.232, 25322940253.7602, 24336863756.7546, 
    25189608620.1855, 25320123456.7901, 26204913699.8426, 24875012907.1837, 
    25699143936.2022, 25918981345.8125, 26828862297.4798, 25723264850.2275, 
    26661451012.6325, 26817952935.6474, 27730546144.1877, 26430891276.2001, 
    27130746121.828, 27368358875.1632, 28188874478.1227, 26963733022.6122, 
    27902101794.5407, 28122691451.4785, 28976253131.2815, 27850026848.0889, 
    28969221937.7692, 29306253136.5783, 30253487806.1969, 29048298910.932, 
    30098753739.0504, 30408387402.9014, 31540170612.6837, 30305991372.9305, 
    31338089796.3896, 31478882110.9967, 32715418840.0953, 31194414618.8931, 
    32499342291.6582, 32363862784.4326, 33280770262.2431, 31711315251.1413, 
    32541277413.1269, 32424964717.3351, 33463380983.8784, 32092466233.7266, 
    33020136505.9471, 33171345823.9365, 34079628256.821, 32485169975.5783, 
    33622439895.2574, 33993253465.9877, 35429094721.0003, 34001121694.55, 
    34866580379.3729, 35240004638.9912, 36545672465.4354, 35073369491.6478, 
    36224490596.7095, 36259363054.5303, 37567995497.0677, 36386704937.3554, 
    37205987767.8273, 37218518705.595, 38417875805.5523, 36948176889.2117, 
    37791365777.0801, 37971495597.3698, 38731965495.01, 37206028775.465, 
    36917087783.2509, 36706267890.3179, 38191521030.4293, 35992161815.5556, 
    36328927601.6361, 36519919105.9246, 37637437647.6766, 35992567528.9789, 
    37456234337.25, 37719401572.6337, 38572862611.8239, 36575417855.0902, 
    37493078351.3241, 37614093088.966, 38643839335.8385, 37524964614.649, 
    38352377413.9263, 38363154075.9308, 39337840045.2824, 37935426334.949, 
    38883827474.8867, 39433742625.5233, 40579643699.2402, 38698152610.1453, 
    39847178231.6809, 40765220450.217, 42052245216.3496, 40460169979.1012, 
    41696304154.5481, 42291908179.2464, 43011309107.3024, 41103224973.4678, 
    42325826513.2009, 42762218814.183, 43473515269.0922, 41587129237.9987, 
    43295806067.6844, 43650735173.9407, 44802283124.4096, 42964921202.462, 
    44493262917.9686, 45003489732.068, 46099768086.1553)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-224L))
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be a bug in the code where we specify only a single `dependent_vars`, the `dimnames` attribute is returning `NULL` for the row.names

```
library(panelvar)
attr(panel_regression$OLS$coef, "dimnames")[[1]]
#NULL
```

It can be checked by building the model with multiple `dependent_vars` which is not the case e.g. (from the e.g. in `?pvarfeols`)

```
data(Cigar)
ex1_feols <-
 pvarfeols(dependent_vars = c("log_sales", "log_price"),
      lags = 1,
      exog_vars = c("cpi"),
      transformation = "demean",
      data = Cigar,
      panel_identifier= c("state", "year"))
summary(ex1_feols)
attr(ex1_feols$OLS$coef, "dimnames")[[1]]
#[1] "demeaned_log_sales" "demeaned_log_price"
```

---

One option is to manually set the `attr`ibute

```
attr(panel_regression$OLS$coef, "dimnames")[[1]] <- "demeaned_Debt"
```

Now, it should work with `summary`

```html
summary(panel_regression)
---------------------------------------------------
Fixed Effects OLS Panel VAR estimation 
---------------------------------------------------
Transformation: demean 
Group variable: Country 
Time variable: Period 
Number of observations = 224 
Number of groups = 2 
Obs per group: min = 112 
               avg = 112 
               max = 112 

=================================
                    demeaned_Debt
---------------------------------
demeaned_lag1_Debt   0.8185 ***  
                    (0.0192)     
demeaned_Fed        -0.0064      
                    (0.0319)     
demeaned_US GDP      0.0000      
                    (0.0000)     
=================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```